# Wiping entire usb drive on Mac OS X

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, usb-drive

Is there a command for the apple terminal to brute force a wipe of everything including all partitions, master boot records, and data on a usb flash drive?

Just a little information about the situation: 
I just got a stick from a friend which seems to be damaged but it isnt a physical defect. I guess he just removed the stick while formatting or so.

I already tried to repartition, reformat and erase the stick with the Mac Disc Utility and I tried to format it on windows. Nothing of it worked, so I decided to use terminal for it (im just getting used to terminal/bash, so im a complete newbie at this) and tried the commands (all with sudo and diskutil in front of them ofc) repairDisk, reformat, partitionDisk, eraseDisk or zeroDisk, but nothing worked. Im getting this error message now: Error: -69759: Securely erasing data to prevent recovery failed
Underlying error: 5: POSIX reports: Input/output error

So my final thought is now that I have to clean everything from this drive as it seems there is something broken on a very low level and i would assume that completely wiping it will result in my diskutil to install a complete new partition scheme and everything on the drive so it will eventually start working again..

Thank you all in advance!

Screenshots:
[image: dd attempt and disk info]

Comment: input/output error probably means, that it's physically defect

Comment: ok - it is pretty new and I assumed that its not physically broken because my friend didnt want to tell me how it broke - he just said "ya i was using it the one day and the next it didnt work anymore"..  so I tried to acces root mode (sudo su) in terminal and then wanted to overwrite erverything on the disk with random stuff, I used the following for it:
 cat /dev/random > /dev/disk3

Now it just says "cat: stdout: Resource busy"

Comment: What about using dd to write zeros to the USB?

Comment: Does this USB stick claim to be unusually large (128+ GB)? It may be a fake.

Comment: The USB stick claims to be 31.5GB, it should have 32GB which is legit i guess and it isnt a noname.. But it is still a cheaper one, its from "Hama". I'll add some screenshots to my post with info about dd and terminals info about the stick. And Thank you for the help guys :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this in Terminal if you are **CERTAIN** it is disk3:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/rdisk3 bs=65536 count=1000
```

If it says the disk is busy, make it un-busy!

```
sudo diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk3
```

Comment: hi mark thanks for the answer! I did as you suggested (today i havent had my other 128GB Stick with me, so the broken one mounted under disk2)
But instead of saying it is busy, now it gives me the following:
dd: /dev/rdisk2: Input/output error
    1+0 records in
    0+0 records out
    0 bytes transferred in 162.661298 secs (0 bytes/sec)

Comment: Mmmm... sounds pretty broken:-(

Comment: yah unfortunately it looks like it is.. :-( another friend of me will now try to repair it with MP Factory Tools, but i really have no clue how this works cause the tools are mainly chinese and he also said its better to learn a bit russian for the documentation and stuff, so I guess this is my last hope now, and my friend who owned the stick already gave up and told me to just throw it away but Im a little bit excited to see if this Factory Tool will work :D

Comment: I don't know if `wipefs` is available on Mac, but if so, it is another tool to use in this circumstance.

Answer (score 3):

First, check what disk# your usb is (to be certain) in a terminal:

```
sudo diskUtil list
```

then

```
sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/<your_usb_disk_here> bs=1m
```

If you get busy error and/or if the usb is in use elsewhere, stop what you are doing there and unmount it first as Mark Setchell said

```
sudo diskutil unmountDisk /dev/<your_usb_disk_here>
```

If you get a funky name from using bootcamp assistant or something, and you cannot get dd or even Disk Utility to wipe it for some reason, like "permission" problem, use:

```
diskutil eraseVolume HFS+ NAME <your_usb_disk_here>
```

Note that the last arg is not e.g. /dev/disk2  , but just the last part, disk2

Comment: At last I got "Error: -69877: Couldn't open device"